# Prove some statement about quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given quadratic form on a finite vector space $V$ over field $K$, $\text{char} K \neq 2$. Prove, that if there exists non-trivial zero $v\in V\setminus 0$, such that $q(v)=0$, then $q$ is surjective mapping.

Comment: What about $q\equiv 0$?

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe non-degenerate q

Answer (score 0):

$\dim V=n$

$q(v)=\sum\limits_{1\leq i \leq n} c_i v_i^2=0 \implies \sum\limits_{1\leq i< n} c_i v_i^2-c_n v_n^2=0$ (without loss of generality, change sign of $c_n$ and reorder $v$ to achieve $v_n\neq 0$).

$y^2=\frac{1}{c_n}\sum\limits_{1\leq i< n} c_i v_i^2, x=v_n$. (divided by $c_n$, get sum is equals to some square $\implies$ it is a square).

$y^2-x^2=0$.

Want to achieve:

$a^2y^2-b^2x^2=\frac{w}{c}$ for all $w\in K, w\neq 0$.

$(ay-bx)(ay+bx)=w$. Find any solution:$ay-bx=1\implies 2ay=w/c+1 \implies a=\frac{w/c+1}{2y} \implies \frac{w/c+1}{2}-bx=1\implies b=\frac{w/c+1-2}{2x}$

Multiply first $n-1$ coordinates of given $v$ by $a$, and $n$-th coordinate by $b$ and achieve $q(v_{new})=w$.